# Cant display data from array(JSON) in my collectionView

Tags: swift

Im super newly in swift (learning a couple of weeks) and sorry for my english. i don't know how to avoid checking method "cellForItemAt indexPath". I tryed to play with refreshingControl but its not working. I got error at the line "let arry = arrayOfData[indexPath.row] // <-- here is got error: Fatal error: Index out of range". If i comment this line all work fine (and refreshControll). My arrayOfData is empty when collectionView trying load, if continue (when i debaging) eventually i will get my data from arrayOfData (its data from JSON). But compiler wont check that method again (if i try check isRefresh true of false).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    private var isRefreshing = true
    var arrayOfData = [GettingMoney]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        collectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl
        collectionView.refreshControl?.beginRefreshing()
        fetchData()

        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self

    }

    func fetchData () {
        let url = "SOMEAPI"
        guard let urlString = URL(string: url) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlString) { (data, _, _) in
            guard let data = data else { return }

            do {

                let getData = try JSONDecoder().decode(GettingMoney.self, from: data)
                print("getSomeData")

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.arrayOfData = [getData]
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                    self.collectionView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
                    print("reload Data")
                }

            } catch {
                print("Its a error")
            }
            }.resume()
    }

}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCellId", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell {

            let arry = arrayOfData[indexPath.row] // <-- here is got error: Fatal error: Index out of range
            print("is Ok")
            cell.currectCurrency.text = "\(arry.USD))"
            print(arrayOfData)

            return cell
        }

        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `numberOfItemsInSections` as below,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.arrayOfData.count
}
```